# jquery.inputmask don't read options from data-inputmask attribute

Tags: jquery

Docs for jquery.inputmask https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#usage says that it is possible to configure plugin behavior via attribute data-inputmask, but this don't work for my code.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.2.4/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.2.4/inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.2.4/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>

<input id="currency1" data-inputmask="'alias': 'currency', 'groupSeparator': '', 'prefix': ''" />
<input id="currency2" />

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#currency1').inputmask();

        jQuery('#currency2').inputmask({
            'alias': 'currency',
            'groupSeparator': '',
            'prefix': ''
        });
    });
</script>
```

First input shows "$", but in code I've wrote that prefix should be empty "'prefix': ''".
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mnEC.png)

Comment: $('input').val('$ ' + $('input').val()); maybe this is easier and will rescue some loadtime, if you use it only for adding `$` into a input.

Comment: I don't want "$" in input, plugin jquery.inputmask adds this to first input

Comment: Then you should wrote more text in your queustion + your question isn't literary a question.

Comment: Pls, don't answer on questions, that are not literary questions

Comment: That's got to be a bug in the plugin surely. If I were you, I'd browse the [issues](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues) and if it's not already there, raise one.

Comment: Yes, it was bug. Will be fixed in next version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may there are problems with this support.

you can also try to write attribute name to data-inputmask attribute like

```
data-inputmask-alias="myAlias"
data-inputmask-prefix="$$"
```

is not nicer to read but may this works *holding hands before eyes*

Comment: No, this don't work, it will require some code to find all inputs with such attributes and than call .inputmask({...}) with this attributes for them.